# How to handle oauth2 using NextJS?

Tags: cookies, next.js, oauth-2.0

Here are my steps of authorization:

1. When the user clicks sign in with a third party oauth provider, the user is redirected to the third party's website.
2. The user signs in using third party and third party returns the data to the redirect address I provided (in my example: http://localhost:3000/api/login). Third party sends GET request with a code attached to its uri query.
3. I use the code provided along with my other credentials to send to the third party endpoint to receive something like this:

   {

   access_token: '1IqfasasdfsadfasdtS795sadfasdfasdfasd',

   refresh_token: '2frsadfasfdat5bGhrs6YTtCqY5h0asdfasdfasdfasdf',

   token_type: 'Bearer',

   expires_in: 3600,

   refresh_expires_in: 2592000,

   scope: 'user_profile'

   }

What is the best way to handle the refresh token and access token? I ideally want to store the access token to browser's session storage and refresh token to http only cookie, but I can't figure out a way to pass the access_token from backend to browser, where for cookie I can just do a res.setHeader, is there something like res.setSessionStorage? Or what are my other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out NextAuthJS? Open source. Built in oauth/oidc providers and supports custom ones too. It was fairly easy to use, once you got the setup right.
https://next-auth.js.org/